# What is the purpose of Global and Final modifiers in Batch Apex?

Tags: apex, batch, global-variables

I've noticed that Batch Apex classes are all global, and the dev console returns an error if you just try to do a public/private class.

My understanding is that a global class is visible to all other code, which would make sense if I'm making a generic Batch Apex processor class that feed calls to other classes to (if you can even do something like that). But what about when the batch process you want to perform is included completely within the body of the batch class - whats the point of having it global in that case?

Separately, I noticed in the first example given on the [Using Batch Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) doc, the global variables have a 'final' modifier. I've been having difficulty finding the documentation on this modifier. Can anyone explain to me what it means, and what it's purpose is in this context?

Here's the example from the documentation:

```
 global class UpdateAccountFields implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
   global final String Query;
   global final String Entity;
   global final String Field;
   global final String Value;

   global UpdateAccountFields(String q, String e, String f, String v){
             Query=q; Entity=e; Field=f;Value=v;
   }

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, 
                       List<sObject> scope){
      for(Sobject s : scope){s.put(Field,Value); 
      }      update scope;
   }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

   }

}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A `Database.Batchable` class has to be a top-level class (not an inner class) but can now be `public`.

When `Database.Batchable` was first available, implementors had no choice but to use the `global` access modifier. For people creating managed packages, this had the very unfortunate consequence of making any `Database.Batchable` part of the managed package's API whether you wanted it to be or not. `global` makes a class usable by code outside of a managed package; `public` makes a class usable by any class within the managed package or within a non-packaged set of source code.

This error has been corrected so that you now have the choice of making the `Database.Batchable` `public` or `global` and `public` is the right choice most of the time. Unfortunately I don't think the documentation has been updated.

`private` not `global` or `public` is the right access modifier for fields most of the time. Sometimes `final` is helpful in communicating intent to the reader and/or enforcing its constraint. But a more important point about fields in a `Database.Batachable` implementation class is that state is not maintained in fields between invocations of the methods unless the implementation class is also marked as `Database.Stateful`.

Comment: Has anyone noticed that batchable class properties _do_ persist between `start()` and `execute()` methods even in the absence of `Database.Stateful` interface?

Comment: Not sure if between execute and execute is different than between start and execute; would need testing. The documentation says "If you don't specify Database.Stateful, all static and instance member variables are set back to their original values" which is not entirely clear.

Comment: From Checkmarx scanner: `It is a common misconception to believe that batch apex or async apex must run with the global keyword. This is not true, the only classes that must be global are those that expose webservices or are intended to be used by extension packages. All async apex should run as public in order to avoid creating privileged entry points to your app.`

Answer (score 2):

I just read through the [SF doc on the 'final' keyword](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_final.htm). Guess that's pretty self-explanatory: the final modifier means you can only assign the value once, upon declaration/initiation. and since the variables in this context only OUGHT to be assigned once, when calling the batch class, then I guess it makes sense.